# Как добавить обработчик события на каждый элемент массива?

Tags: javascript

Нужна ваша помощь, только начал изучать обработчики событий.

```
var pictures = [..массив сгенерированных объектов];  
var showBigPicture = function (smallPicture) {..};
var picturesList = document.querySelectorAll('.picture');

for (var i = 0; i < picturesList.length; i++) {
  var index = i;
  picturesList[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
    showBigPicture(pictures[index]);
}
```

В результате клика по любому **picturesList[i]** event.target и отображаемая картинка всегда равны последнему элементу **pictures[]**, а нужно чтобы была показана картинка, на которой был клик.
Подскажите, где я ошибся?

Comment: Вот здесь вы ошиблись: showBigPicture(pictures[index]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что на момент выполнения

```
function () {
    showBigPicture(pictures[index]);
}
```

У вас переменная index будет равна последнему индексу в массиве, тут почитайте про разницу между let и var.

```
const pictures = [..массив сгенерированных объектов];  
const showBigPicture = function (smallPicture) {..};
const picturesList = document.querySelectorAll('.picture');

for (let i = 0; i < picturesList.length; i++) {
  picturesList[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
    showBigPicture(pictures[i]);
}
```

Попробуйте этот код